# Facing this error when making docker run postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

Ran this command:
$ docker run -d \

> ```
> --name some-postgres \
> -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
> -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
> -v /custom/mount:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
> postgres
> ```

Error:
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
The path /custom/mount is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac for more info.

How do i resolve this???

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the path you are trying to mount is not configured as shareable in the Docker Desktop preferences. You can either add the folder to be shareable or you can use a folder which is already configured.